# Rails and Postgres Hstore: Can you add an index in a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing, migration, hstore

I have a migration where I create a products table like so

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.hstore :data

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

On the [activerecord-postgres-hstore page](https://github.com/softa/activerecord-postgres-hstore) they add an index to the table (in SQL) with

```
CREATE INDEX products_gin_data ON products USING GIN(data);
```

However that change is not tracked by migrations (I'm guessing because it's Postgres specific?), is there a way to create an index from within a migration?

thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes! You can make another migration and use the 'execute' method... like so:

```
class IndexProductsGinData < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "CREATE INDEX products_gin_data ON products USING GIN(data)"
  end

  def down
    execute "DROP INDEX products_gin_data"
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:** You might also want to specify this line in config/application.rb:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

You can read about it here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/schema_format/class

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the tip on `config.active_record.schema_format`

Comment: Additionally you may want to make it: CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY products_gin_data ON products USING GIN(data) this would allow it to not lock the table while its adding the index.

Comment: You can also use CONCURRENTLY on the DROP.

Answer (score 28):

In Rails 4, you can now do something like this in a migration:

```
    add_index :products, :data, using: :gin
```

Comment: This does not generate the GIN(data). Might be bug in the generator.

Comment: gave me this in my structure.sql (Rails 4.0.2):
CREATE INDEX index_products_on_data ON products USING gin (data);