# Migration of trigram search in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, pg-search, trigram

I have a migration:

```
class AddGinIndexToContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute("CREATE INDEX contacts_search_idx ON contacts USING gin (first_name gin_trgm_ops, last_name gin_trgm_ops, name gin_trgm_ops)")
  end

  def down
    execute("DROP INDEX contacts_search_idx")
  end
end
```

It generates this code in `schema.rb`:

```
add_index "contacts", ["first_name", "last_name", "name"], name: "contacts_search_idx", using: :gin
```

and later, when I execute `rake db:schema:load` it generates wrong sql:

```
CREATE  INDEX  "contacts_search_idx" ON "contacts" USING gin ("first_name", "last_name", "name")
```

Firstly, it says:

> ERROR:  data type character varying has no default operator class for
>   access method "gin"

Secondly, there are lost `gin_trgm_ops`.

How to make it works?

`Rails 4.2`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the order param to define the operator class.

```
add_index "contacts", ["first_name", "last_name", "name"], name: "contacts_search_idx", using: :gin, order: {first_name: :gin_trgm_ops, last_name: :gin_trgm_ops, name: :gin_trgm_ops}
```

Found this solution here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index#1553-Adding-index-with-other-operator-classes-PostgreSQL-

Comment: Thank you, but it still generates wrong schema.rb without gin_trgm_ops

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this cannot be solved unless schema is changed to sql. Few links:

[Rails and Postgres Hstore: Can you add an index in a migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592221/rails-and-postgres-hstore-can-you-add-an-index-in-a-migration)

[Why does add_index using 'gin' create a 'btree' index instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185434/why-does-add-index-using-gin-create-a-btree-index-instead)

Once I have changed schema format to sql it works fine.

Comment: You should include the important information from the links, and add them as reference. Please have a look at the help center

Answer (score 1):

You can nowadays use the `opclass` option:

```
add_index :contacts, [:first_name, :last_name, :name], name: "contacts_search_idx", using: :gin, opclass: { first_name: :gin_trgm_ops, last_name: :gin_trgm_ops, name: :gin_trgm_ops }
```

Comment: It's showing me an error like this 'Unknown key: :opclass. Valid keys are: :unique, :order, :name, :where, :length, :internal, :using, :algorithm, :type'

Comment: NOTE: `opclass` option requires Rails 5.2+

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `btree_gin` Postgres [extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/btree-gin.html) in order to use GIN indexes.

Simply add `enable_extension('btree_gin')` to the migration and it all should work fine.